# Python easygui module

Tags: python, easygui

In this code:

```
#! street.py
# A simple program which tests GUI

import easygui

easygui.msgbox("This programe asks for your info and stores them")
name = easygui.enterbox("What is your name?")
hNumber = easygui.enterbox("What is your house number")
street = easygui.enterbox("What is your post number?")
city = easygui.enterbox("What is your city?")
country = easygui.enterbox("What is your country?")

easygui.msgbox(name +  
               hNumber +
               street +
               city +
               country)
```

I have problems with the last window(easygui.msgbox(....), I want to display all info in a single window at different lines but I can only get it to display on a single line.
`\n` and similar doesn't work.

Comment: I think you need to pass `msgbox()` the strings in a list, like `easygui.msgbox([name, hNumber, street, city, country])`.

Answer (score 1):

This might work with `"\n"`

```
easygui.msgbox('\n'.join([
               name,
               hNumber,
               street,
               city,
               country]))
```

Answer (score 1):

i tried this, you can try out my fixed version.

```
import easygui
easygui.msgbox("This programe asks for your info and stores them")
name = easygui.enterbox("What is your name?")
hNumber = easygui.enterbox("What is your house number")
street = easygui.enterbox("What is your post number?")
city = easygui.enterbox("What is your city?")
country = easygui.enterbox("What is your country?")
easygui.msgbox(name + '\n' + hNumber + '\n' + street + '\n' + city + '\n' + country)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
easygui.msgbox(name + "\n" + hNumber + "\n" + street + "\n" +
               city + "\n" + country)
```

A bit longer but works as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use newest `easygui` version `0.98.1` and it's `multenterbox` option.

so your code would be:

```
#! street.pyw
# A simple program which tests GUI
import easygui
easygui.msgbox("This programe asks for your info and stores them")
info = easygui.multenterbox('Fill fields below','Info',['Name','Number','Street','City','Country'])
first = info[0]
second = info[1]
third = info[2]
fourth = info[3]
fiveth = info[4]
easygui.msgbox(first+'\n'+second+'\n'+third+'\n'+fourth+'\n'+fiveth)
```

And better save it as `scriptname.pyw` not `scriptname.py`.